# Are Yondu's new fins earlier versions of his original fin or are they newer versions?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

**Are Yondu's second fin and Kraglin's first fin earlier prototypes of the fin from Volume 1 or are they new prototypes?**

Yondu tells Groot that the fin is a prototype fin.

When I first saw Volume 2 I assumed that this was a new fin that he had been working on, but it was still in the prototyping stages.

Thinking more about it I could also see this being an older fin that Yondu replaced with the one from Volume 1. This might explain why he keeps the "prototype fin" in, what appears to be, his junk drawer; he does not really need it, but it could be useful one day. This might also explain why the fin is much larger than his Volume 1 fin (besides aesthetics).

Comment: Pretty sure the fin in the drawer is the _original_ "prototype" - it was supposed to be a nod to Yondu's original look from the comics and explain that he got a new, sleeker fin for Volume 1.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate that's been answered elsewhere

Comment: @HorusKol That is what I am thinking. Especially since it goes back to his original look.

Comment: @Edlothiad I was not aware that this was a duplicate. I did search the stack before asking the question.

Comment: @Josafoot i’m probably wrong, but I’d thought so, it’s not a negative thing though and I meant no disrespect.

Comment: @Edlothiad None taken :) I was more wondering if I missed a previous post.

Answer (score 6):

I can't find any clear information each way, my personal opinion is that it was an early design of the fin and that the newer sleeker one is a later development on the early one.

With that said [the script here](http://waltdisneystudiosawards.com/media/scripts/GotG2.pdf) only ever calls it a fin but never mentions if it was created before or after the sleeker one. The closest is "Yondu's current model" but that doesn't really state either way.

> Yondu: In the Cap’n’s quarters, there’s a prototype fin, like the thing I
>   wore on my head.
>   ...
>   Yondu: All right. It’s a prototype fin -
>   ...
>   Rocket: That’s an orloni. It’s a fin, Groot.
>   ...
>   *Beside some writing instruments and a tin of candies, there lies a RED FIN, taller and more shark-like than Yondu’s current model. Groot smiles hugely, picking up -*
>   ...
>   *The RED FIN PLOPS DOWN at Yondu’s feet.*
>   ...
>   *Yondu, sitting calmly; Rocket is finishing ATTACHING THE BIG ASS FIN TO HIS HEAD. Its electrical systems POP on.*
>   ...
>   *Taserface is awoken by JAY AND THE AMERICANS on the PA. He glances over to see the open drawer beside him, sans gargantuan fin.*
>   ...
>   Taserface: HE’S GOT IT! YONDU’S GOT THE DAMN FIN!
>   ...
>   Nebula: If he’s got that fin back, I am so screwed.
>   ...
>   *SURRENDER is PLAYING HERE. Kraglin has had a version of Yondu’s fin implanted in his head. He looks nervously down at the arrow on the floor.*
>   <sub>Guardians Of The Galaxy Vol. 2</sub>

The [MCU wikia](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Yaka_Arrow_Controller) page on the Yaka Arrow Controller appears to believe the prototype is a newer model but cites no sources for it's case.

> Having developed a second controller, Yondu eventually used it, with the help of Rocket and Groot, to escape captivity and kill the Ravager mutineers. He then used the controller during the Battle on Ego's Planet.

Lastly, [Yondu in Earth-616](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Yondu_Udonta_(Earth-616)) has the smaller fin like in Vol. 1 and the page states it's modelled after the film Yondu (Earth-199999). Whereas [Yondu in Earth-691](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Yondu_Udonta_(Earth-691)) has the taller shark like fin. I'd assume that the prototype fin is then a reference to Yondu's original appearance in the comics but it still isn't exactly clear if it's newer or not.

[image: Yondu - Earth-616] [image: Yondu - Earth-691]

---

On a side note the script above makes a mention that the fin Kraglin uses is not the same prototype that Yondu uses. This makes sense as Yondu still has the fin on his head when

> he is cremated.